# TeamCity: How to show parameters in the history

Tags: teamcity

I have 3 servers for PROD, with the same deployment build configuration, I choose which server to deploy depending on a build parameter.
The issue is that reviewing the history you can't check which environment are you deploying.

I wonder if it's possible one of this solutions:
 - Show parameters in the history of a build
 - Autotag a build with parameters

I hope I had explained well enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a Command Line build step that echoes the relevant parameters to the build log.  For a Windows-based agent, you could do something like:

- Run: `Executable with parameters`
- Command Executable: `echo`
- Command Parameters: `Deployed to server %your.server.host%`

This would simply add a line to the build log that reads, `Deployed to server FOO`

Autotagging would be pretty cool, but I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: [Here](http://blog.minodudd.com/2014/01/automatically-pin-and-tag-builds-in-teamcity/) is a blog post describing how to setup a script to autotag.